# Using boolean return values in a .NET dll used in Installscript

Tags: c#, installscript

I have created a .NET dll to be used in Installscript. It basically installs certificates, removes certificates and checks if a certificate already exists.
This is my Exists method:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public bool Exists(string thumbPrint)
{
    try
    {
        ...
        //Check if the certificate exists on the store.
        var certCollection = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbPrint, false);
        return (certCollection.Count > 0);

    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

This is the installscript code

```
szDLLPath = SUPPORTDIR ^ "X509Framework.dll";   
szClassName = "X509Framework.X509StoreProcessor";
DotNetUnloadAppDomain("X509FrameworkDomain");
try
    set oX509Store = DotNetCoCreateObject(szDLLPath, szClassName, "X509FrameworkDomain");
catch
    SprintfBox (INFORMATION, "Error","Error occured: %i\n\n%s\n\n%s", Err.Number, Err.Description, Err.LastDllError); 
    abort;
endcatch; 

try
    nReturn = oX509Store.Exists(FinArchCodeSigningSha);
catch
    SprintfBox (INFORMATION, "Error","Error occured: %i\n\n%s\n\n%s", Err.Number, Err.Description, Err.LastDllError); 
    abort;
endcatch;
```

In this example `nReturn` is always `-1` when I debug it in Installscript, whether the certificate exists or not. (of course from a .NET program it works fine)
Then I tried to use an `int` as return value and this worked. So there is a workaround.

But I was wondering if anyone knows why I cannot use `bool` as return value for a .NET dll that is used in Installscript.

Comment: Not sure but just give a try to return integer from `Exists(string thumbPrint)` method. Success 0, unsuccessful -1

Comment: Thanks for the hint GAPS. I've done some tests with return `int` values from .NET and catching them in a `BOOL` variable in InstallScript and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end it turned out to be quite simple. Installshield cannot interpret the Boolean field from .NET. Had to use an int instead.

The .NET program had to return an `int` value:
`1` for `TRUE` and `0` for `FALSE` (pretty standard I know)

Then I set the return value into a `BOOL` variable in Installshield.